# How to pass credentials to a SOAP webservice?

Tags: c#, web-services, soap

I am trying to call a SOAP webservice, however I am getting the error:
Additional information: The username is not provided. Specify username in ClientCredentials.

So I thought I could just set client.ClientCredentials to a new instance of NetworkCredentials.  However ClientCredentials is read only.  So how can I go about passing this information on to access the web service?

```
    myService.ServiceClient client = new myService.ServiceClient();
    // This won't work since its read only.                
    client.ClientCredentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password", "domain");
    string version = client.getData();
```

EDIT:
Binding:

```
  <binding name="VersionHttpBinding">
    <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
      <transport clientCredentialType="Basic" />
    </security>
  </binding>
```

Comment: What is the authentication method of the web service?  Basic authentication or something else?

Comment: Updated as requested.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You'll need to set the credentials on the client, like as shown [in this MSDN article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/transport-security-with-basic-authentication):

```cs
client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "my_user_name";
client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "my_password";
```

Comment: I'm 99% sure I've done exactly this in the past. Did you try and replace the entire object (which I believe *is* read-only), or setting the individual properties on the object, as in the example.

Comment: .Username.Password. Hilarious

Comment: Is providing passwords in this way secure or it requires SSL to be implemented as well?

Comment: You should always use HTTPS and TLS if exchanging credentials. I'm not sure as I can't remember and haven't used WCF for some time, but it might even be a requirement of the WCF APIs that you must use HTTPS with username and password.

Comment: @Martin Costello: It is no requirement. Your solution, combined with an app.config that is configured the way John Doe shows it, does work.

Comment: I was giving up when I saw "Username" {get}